# Androidのホーム画面にアプリへのショートカットを追加したい

Tags: android

Androidのホーム画面にアプリへのショートカットを作成する、ということをJavaのプログラムで行いたいのですが、可能ですか？

Answer (score 1):

[ホーム画面上にショートカットを作成する方法](http://monoist.atmarkit.co.jp/mn/articles/1203/16/news006.html)の記事がありましたので紹介します。

１．マニフェストにパーミッションを追加する

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

２．下記のコードを実装する

> ```
> /** アプリのショートカットを作成 */
> private void makeAppShortCut(Context con){
>     // アプリケーションを起動するためのIntentを作成
>     // 今回はこのアプリ自身（ShortCutTestActivity）を起動するようにした
>     Intent targetIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MAIN );
>     targetIntent.setClassName( con, "jp.test.shortcut.ShortCutTestActivity" );
>
>     // ショートカットのタイトルは“APPShortCut”
>     // アイコンにはあらかじめ作成しておいた「tips_icon.png」を使用
>     makeShortCut(con, targetIntent, "APPShortCut", R.drawable.tips_icon );
> }
> /** ショートカット作成の処理 */
> private void makeShortCut(Context con, Intent targetIntent, String title, int iconResource){
>     // ショートカット作成依頼のためのIntent
>     Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
>
>     // ショートカットのタップ時に起動するIntentを指定
>     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, targetIntent);
>
>     // ショートカットのアイコンとタイトルを指定
>     Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(con, iconResource);
>     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
>     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, title);
>
>     // BroadCastを使って、システムにショートカット作成を依頼する
>     con.sendBroadcast(intent);
> }
> ```

---

また、マニフェストに`intent-filter`で`scheme`が設定されていた場合
対象のアプリをURLで開くことが可能になりますので、
WEBリンクを作成する方法でも上記機能を実装することが可能です。